# How do I solve this Yii2 RESTful Web Service API routing error?

Tags: rest, yii2

I am trying to implement the Yii2 RESTful Web Service API as described in the guide. I am trying it using the advanced application template. The problem is simply that all I get are 404 errors when I try to access the service. I wanted to start out trying something simple so I was simply going to use a country table and associated ActiveRecord class to try it out, here's the code:

This is in the components configuration in frontend/config/main.php :

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'country'],
        ],
    ],
    'request' => [
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
        ]
    ]
```

This is the code in frontend/controllers/CountryController.php :

```
namespace frontend\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class CountryController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Country';
}
```

All of my ActiveRecord models like country are in common/models.

I used the following to try it:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://myfrontendapp.loc/country"
```

This is the output I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 22:46:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 205
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /country was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

I have spent many hours on this. I have adjusted the setting, read documentation, and alot more without any success. If anyone can see what the problem is please let me know, thanks!!

Comment: I tried it with the basic application template and had no problems whatsoever. If anyone figures out how to do this using the advanced application template let me know.

Answer (score 5):

You're hit by the default `UrlRule` behavior of pluralizing class names: in line with common REST conventions, it's smart enough to turn a controller named `country` into a pluralized route named `/countries`.

Try to `GET http://myfrontendapp.loc/countries` and it'll most likely work fine. This also goes for all other routes created by UrlRule, e.g. `GET /countries/12345`

Or, if you want to disable this behavior you can set UrlRule's `$pluralize` to false. Check http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html for more information.

Comment: I noticed that in the docs and I tried it, both "countries" and "countrys" with the exact same result, no luck. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

According to yii2 rest standards while running your application you have to very specific with your URI i.e. as you are running the application for country so while running pluralize it so while running you should run as http://myfrontendapp.loc/countries.
But still you want country only then in your `main.php` under your urlmanager type `'controller'=>['c','country']`. And if your problem still persists then you need to check your dir structure... It should be yii dir
api, backend, frontend under api their should be config, modules inside moudles --v1 and inside v1-- countrollers and models.
etc.
This will surely resolve your issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- In `advanced/api/web/index.html` add `require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');` instead of `require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/aliases.php');`
- In `advanced/common/config/bootstrap.php` add `Yii::setAlias('api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');`
- Look through [this tutorial](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/)

And make sure your GET request is correct. Remove 'api/web' from reqesst line. Just use v1/countrys

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed

> .htaccess

in the folder, if not create the

> .htaccess

with the following content

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Or you can check the request with the following url once, as you are using advanced templaet

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://myfrontendapp.loc/frontend/web/index.php?r=countries"
```

One more thing to remember folder names are also case-sensitive while declaring namespaces, so please check the folder names as well.